# Queries regarding firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the firebase realtime database in my android app. I only want the last entry inserted into the database and not an entire database sync.I am doing the following.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("reference").limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(this);
```

Here's what I could not clearly understand :

1.When I do a limitToLast and add a listener, does it download the entire data from the database into the local copy and pass me a snapshot of the last entry or does it download only the last entry?

2.When I remove the listener , does the sync stop between the realtime database and the local data or the sync keeps happening but the onDataChange is not called?

3.The difference between removing the Value Event listener and going Offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `limitToLast()` you create a Firebase Database query. Such a query only synchronizes the data that it matches, so in your example it only downloads the last item and invokes `onDataChange` with it. Then when somebody adds a new item, it  invokes `onDataChange` again with the new last item.

Removing a listener stops the data synchronization.

Going offline temporarily stops data synchronization, until you call `goOnline()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.The Usage tab in my Firebase console shows that I am downloading ~2MB per hour even though I don't have any active listeners during the period.Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: It's hard to say from such limited information. But if you check the Network tab of the Chrome developer tools, you can see the exact traffic in the WS (for web sockets) panel. If it's downloading more data than matches the query, you may have forgotten to [put an index on the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data). You'll also see a warning in the JavaScript console in that case.

Comment: I have not put indexes on data, but why would that download more data than necessary?

Comment: Yes. In that case the entire data at the location will be downloaded and the ordering/filtering will be done client side. But if you have no listeners attached, as you said in your first comment, then that wouldn't apply.

Comment: Since the node's key is indexed automatically and since I am using limitToLast I assumed I don't have to add an explicit index.